# Cannot create VM with multiple NICs in Azure

Tags: azure, networking, cloud, openstack, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to build an OpenStack cloud in Azure (for OpenStack experimentation) that implements [this](http://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/environment-networking.html) network architecture.

I have built everything with Azure CLI and got it working right down to the VM creation but receive the following error when adding the second NIC.

```
error:   Deployment provisioning state was not successful
error:   Subnet default referenced by resource /subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/openstack/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/controller-prov-nic/ipConfigurations/ipconfig2 is not in the same Virtual Network as the subnets of other VMs in the availability set.
```

Networking is not my strength. Why can't I have two NICs that network to their own VNET? Can anyone suggest how best to implement the topology in the OpenStack link above?

You can download the whole project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7LD9BBJctt3b0RxSS0wYWZsVkU). The project builds each resource type in succession. This makes it easier to work with each template file.

Note:

1. You need to edit one line in template.json in the VM directory to
   add your own public SSH key.
2. To build the entire stack (using bash
   and Azure CLI) just run ./build-all.sh in the top directory. (Assuming you have your Azure credentials stored locally. If not
   remove the -n switch in build-all.sh.)
3. My project has only built up to the Controller node in the OpenStack pattern listed above.

Thanks

Bryon

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem....
I did not realise you can set up multiple subnets in a single VNET and then connect each NIC to each subnet. Here is the JSON that solved the problem:

```
    "resources": [
    {
        "comments": "VNet definition for OpenStack Network Layout.",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_os_vnet_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "addressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    "10.0.0.0/16",
                    "203.0.113.0/24"
                ]
            },
            "subnets": [
                {
                    "name": "Management-Network",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Provider-Network",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "203.0.113.0/24"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": []
    }
```

Then the NIC definition becomes:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "comments": "Controller NIC for Management Network",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaces_controller_mgt_nic_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAddress": "10.0.0.11",
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                        "publicIPAddress": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_pub_ip_mgt_ctrlr_name'))]"
                        },
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_os_vnet_name')), '/subnets/Management-Network')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "dnsSettings": {
                "dnsServers": []
            },
            "enableIPForwarding": false,
            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_management_nsg_name'))]"
            }
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": []
    },
    {
        "comments": "Controller NIC for Provider Network",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaces_controller_prov_nic_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfig2",
                    "properties": {
                        "privateIPAddress": "203.0.113.4",
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                        // "publicIPAddress": {
                        //     "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_pub_ip_prov_ctrlr_name'))]"
                        // },
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_os_vnet_name')), '/subnets/Provider-Network')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "dnsSettings": {
                "dnsServers": []
            },
            "enableIPForwarding": false,
            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroups_provider_nsg_name'))]"
            }
        },
        "resources": [],
        "dependsOn": []
     }
  ]
```